# How to increase Resistance of a conductive material?

Tags: electricity, electrical-resistance, conductors

I'm working on a project that I should measure the resistance of conductive sample ( like brass ). But I've a problem. Resistance of conductive samples is too low which requires a miliohm meter to measure that.

Is there any way to increase the resistance to that extent that I'd be able to measure that with usual ohm meter?

Comment: If the resistance is not *too* low, you could try to use a [Four-terminal sensing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Four-terminal_sensing) set up.

Comment: You make very thin, very long samples. In practice it's probably far easier to get hold of a milliohm meter or to build one yourself than to draw brass into thin wires. Seriously... don't try to invent workarounds for problems that can be solved with readily available industrial equipment.

Comment: @CuriousOne: Aren't these workarounds what physics is all about? Good answer though.

Comment: @Numrok: What the OP is trying to do is really an engineering, not a physics problem. Engineering is all about doing things economically. A used, calibrated high quality milliohm meter can be had on eBay for maybe $500. I can only guess what it would cost him to buy a wire drawing machine, the dies and precision micrometer to make a wire sample of reasonably well characterized thickness. This is really a non-problem, unless we make it into one by denying ourselves the right test and measurement tools.

Comment: Fair enough, of course one can use the technology if it exists. In experimental physics on the frontiers it often doesn't though, so looking for these "workarounds" is good practice in my opinion.